# Keyboard navigation JQuery

Tags: jquery, navigation, key

I created a website very simmilar to http://themeforest.s3.amazonaws.com/116_parallax/tutorial-source-files/tut-index.html. Now i want to add key navigation. So when I push arrow right it will go to box2, when arrow left go back to Home.
I tried this tutorial http://jqueryfordesigners.com/adding-keyboard-navigation/

So:

```
$().ready(function() {

$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
var direction = null;

// handle cursor keys
if (event.keyCode == 37) {
  // go left

  direction = 'prev';
} else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
  // go right
  direction = 'next';
}

if (direction != null) {
  $('.coda-slider-wrapper ul a#current').parent()[direction]().find('a').click();
}
});
});
```

And

```
<div id="header" class="coda-slider-wrapper">
    <h1 id="logo">Scrolling Clouds</h1>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#box1" class="link" id="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#box2" class="link">Box 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#box3" class="link">Box 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#box4" class="link">Box 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Unfortunetly it wont work properly becouse only one elemnt has id="current". 
How to get it working? How to add dynamic id? Please write me all the code.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `#current` on whatever link is current.  To do that, use code like this:

```
$(function(){
    var list = $('.coda-slider-wrapper ul');
    list.find('a').click(function(e){
        list.find('a').removeAttr('id');
        this.id = 'current';
    });
});
```